# How to retrieve library version in gradle task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Suppose that the project dependencies are declared as follows:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'io.mylib:core:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    // ....
}
```

I would like to have a gradle task that will retrieve the `mylib` dependency  and check the version. If the version of the lib is `SNAPSHOT` then fail the build.

Something like this:

```
task checkLibVersion(){
   version = getDependencyVersion("io.mylib:core") // <-- how to retrieve version

   if(version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT"){
      throw new GradleException("Mylib uses snapshot version")
   }
}
```

This task would be part of the release pipeline and will fail the job if current version of `mylib` is snapshot.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the version of a particular dependency from a gradle task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it seems this can be done pretty easy if the version number is extracted into an extension property:

In the `build.gradle` of the root project:

```
buildscript {
    ext.libVersion = '1.3.21-SNAPHOT'
    // ....
}

task checkLibVersion(){
    def version = "$libVersion"

    if (version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")){
        throw new GradleException("Mylib uses SNAPSHOT version!")
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.dependsOn checkLibVersion()
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have a task    `configurations {
           implementation.dependencies.each {
               dep -> if(dep.name == 'core'){
                   println dep.version // you get the version of the lib
               }
           }
       }` and have tasks.whenTaskAdded as it is.